# Mysql, update table between day-month any year

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with all days for 10 years in rows (one row per day).

I need to update all rows between a date set, lets say for example from 4th april until 10th June, and for all years in the table.

How can I do it without doing an update for each year?
This is the query:

```
     $query = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE table
     SET price_client=:price_client
     WHERE date between '04-04' and '06-10");
```

Comment: What is the format/type of the `date` column in your table?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just change the date format to `%m-%d` and compare it with your value.

Try below query:

```
 $query = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE table
 SET price_client=:price_client
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m-%d') between '04-04' and '06-10'");
```